# What's the equiv. Swift Closure-Callback to Objective-C's block callback?

Tags: swift, callback

I'm trying to translate the following Objective-C callback:

```
typedef void (^MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler)(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error);
```

[image]

...into its equivalent Swift callback:

```
typealias MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler = (MKLocalSearchResponse!, NSError!) -> Void
```

[image]

...obvious I lost my way here. 
What would be the correct 'shell' or 'structure' of the Swift callback?

Comment: In general it's better practice to copy and paste your code instead of a screen shot of your code, the former is far more legible.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is incorrect. It should be

```
let handler : MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler = { (r: MKLocalSearchResponse?, e: NSError?)  in /*do something*/ }
```

and better to omit the argument type and let compiler infer it

```
let handler : MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler = { r, e in /*do something*/ }
```

BTW, when you post question next time, use text instead of image. So I can copy & paste & modify your code and it is also searchable by others.