# Listen to Objective-C callback in Swift syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an Objective-C callback that looks like this.

```
//APIClient.h
typedef void (^DetailSearchFinishedCallBack)(RestaurantDetailModel *detailModel);

//Called in a different class as follows. 

@property (nonatomic, copy)   DetailSearchFinishedCallBack detailSearchFinishedCallBack;

self.detailSearchFinishedCallBack(nil);
```

In a Swift class I want to be able to listen to this callback but I'm having trouble finding the proper syntax for this call. Here is my swift code:

```
lazy var apiClient: APIClient =
    {
        var apiClient : APIClient = APIClient()

        //TODO: Set up callback listener here.

        return apiClient
    }()
```

I checked this post:
[What's the equiv. Swift Closure-Callback to Objective-C's block callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496366/whats-the-equiv-swift-closure-callback-to-objective-cs-block-callback)

But the block is defined locally and my block is defined in the apiClient. If someone could help me with this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this should work in place of the TODO

```
apiClient.detailSearchFinishedCallBack = { detailModel in
    // Do something with detailModel if not nil
}
```

The type for detailModel will be inferred but you can also be explicit

```
apiClient.detailSearchFinishedCallBack = { (detailModel: RestaurantDetailModel!) in
    // Do something with detailModel if not nil
}
```